I'm trying to design a CE BJT amplifier with 260 gain and Bandwidth of 5.5Mhz
I'm struggling to design a common-emitter BJT amplifier for my college project.
for this i selected a BC547 transistor and I have done the calculations by Assuming my Vcc as 12V. then I took Vce = 5V and Ic = 2mA.
Based on those values I got
Ie = 2mA
re = 25mA / 2mA = 12.5 ohms
Re = 250 ohms
Rc = 260 * re = 3.25 kohms
Voltage divider resistors ratio as R1 = 9 R2

I try to use my lower cutoff frequency as 100Hz, So I calculated values for my capacitors, and the final circuit I designed is as below.

I simulated the circuit with proteus. and got results as below.


Then i input 10mV 150Hz signal and got below results from the simulation.

I just don't know why the amplified signal amplitudes are changing. its not symmetric. and the gain here is 1.49V / 0.01V = 149. But I want 260 gain. with bandwidth of 5.5Mhz

I'm sorry but, you won't reliably realize that gain with any measure of signal quality from a single transistor (even one much faster than the 547). Please reduce your expectations and design a two stage amplifier instead.

The required gain-bandwidth product here is 260 × 5.5MHz = 1430MHz.  Agree with Andy, this is way too high to achieve with a single BJT without resorting to using very special types (& hence rare & expensive).  No chance of achieving this with a single BC547. The lower cut-off frequency is not the issue here, proper selection of capacitors will give that (although the calculated values might be impractical).

Is "bandwidth" = 5.5 MHz ... or "center" frequency = 5.5 MHz ? What kind of "amplifier" is it?

48.3 dB  and at 5.5 MHz. That's not happening in a single BJT CE stage.

2 GHz gain bandwidth products are non trivial.

@Andyaka, can you tell me how to archive this gain and bandwidth range? It will be really appreciated.

@FabioBarone If I have to design this with two transistors, can you give me little guidance on how to get that required gain with the selected bandwidth of 5.5 Mhz. (Low f = 100Hz)

The process to design such an amplifier depends on what you are trying to achieve.  For example:  You mentioned you a student.  Will this amplifier design only be simulated (by Proteus software), or will you build it as a real working circuit and verify it in the lab?  If the latter, then how will you be implementing it: on a proto-typing board or on a PCB?  We can advise you how to go about designing a two-stage CE BJT amplifier, however, perhaps that is not what your teachers had in mind - perhaps they want you to attempt to build a single-stage amplifier in order to learn its limitations?

Also, the set of specifications for the amplifier performance in the OP is not complete.  A complete set of specifications will include:
Input signal source: waveshape (sinewave is assumed unless otherwise specified), amplitude, frequency range, and impedance (is the signal low impedance, eg: 50Ω signal generator, or a high-impedance (over 1kΩ).  Output Load: what is the load connected to the output of this amplifier, eg: an 8Ω speaker or a scope probe with resistance and capacitance (1MΩ||20pF).  Power Supply: how many supply rails are available (just 1, or 2 pos & neg)...

cont'd: and is there a current limit (aka "budget") for each supply voltage that is not to be exceeded?  What is the temperature range that the amplifier has to meet all of the electrical specifications?   Are certain types of components not permitted? Eg: electrolytic capacitors are sometimes not permitted in real-world products for commercial reasons; whereas for education projects op-amps are sometimes not permitted.

All of that said, in regards to designing a CE amplifier stage, you may find this helpful: electronics.stackexchange.com/a/688522/341959

@FabioBarone Thank you very much for your help.

We have to prototype it and after that we have to make a PCB for the circuit. We have our own freedom to select the input signal , but the input signal must coming from the function generator in our laboratory. As you thought we are amplifying Sine wave like to be have 10mV. We doint have details of input impedance of the Function generator.  Frequency range also we can choose. But we have to only amplify our selected bandwitdh of 5.5 Mhz .

as @Andy aka answered, I checked it with some calculations:
Did you check, that UCE is 5 V, your schematic forces UB to be 1.2V or lower (with IB).
Assuming UBE to be 0.6 to 0.7 V, UR2 is between 0.6 to 0.5 V.
Therefore IR2 = IE is about 2.4 to 2 mA.
BC547 can have a hFE of 110 min to 800 at 2mA and 5 V UCE
(https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf)
--> IB between ca. 23 uA and 2.5 uA, so IC = ca. IE
--> UR1 = ca. 6.5 to 7.8 V -> UCE = 12 - (7.8 + 0.6 ... 6.5 + 0.5) = 3.2 ... 5 V.
So 3.2 (...5) V - 1.64 V (lowest point output "sine") would give 1.56 V UCE <-- I assume this area could be outside linear area.
but with 1.56 V UCE, UR2 still 0.6 V or more?
Then UR1 ca. 12 - 1.56 - 0.6 = ca. 9.8 V.
IR1 is then 9.8 / 3.25 = ca. 3 mA
But IR2 is still only 2.4 mA.
so 0.6 mA has to flow into the C1 with 133 uF.
With U * C = I * t , 150 Hz = 3.3 ms long half period
UC1 should not change more go up more than ca. 0.2 V.
0.2 V * 133 uF = 26.6 uC -> divide by 0.6 mA = 44.3 ms = ok
Above the IB is between 23 and 2.5 uA - with no input the U divisor with R3 and R4 has is a 1.2 V source with internal resistor of 3.6k//40k = ca. 3.3 k
with 23 uA and 3.3k this is already 76 mV (compared to 2.5 uA with 3.3 k = ca. 8 mV) -> so this is already a range of 68 mV for the UB, what moves the DC working point also quite.
I think,

you should use a smaller input signal (that output signal is smaller and keeps in linear area of UCE)
first take a reasonable frequency in the unattentuated area like 1 kHz to get it working there
check the DC working point, perhaps too unstable with all the temperature drift, hFE, R tolerances in real world
a more stable DC working point can only be achieved with (AFAIK) a lower gain (due to e. g. a feedback path from C to B with a resistor and/or lowpass)

PS: in the datasheet - I linked - Figure 2 - with 2.5 uA to 23 uA UBE is even less than 0.57 V, estimated 0.5V -> UR2 even 0.7V, IR2 = IE = 2.8 mA
and IC = 2.78 mA ... 2.798 mA = IR1 -> UR1 = 2.8 mA * 3.25 k = 9.1 V, so UCE = 12 - UR1 - UR2 = 12 - 9.1 - 0.7 = 2.2 V, the output swings -1.65 V -> 0.55 V UCEmin
Figure 1 in datasheet with IB = 50 uA show already unlinearity at UCE 1 V
And all figures are typical values...
So your DC working point seems to be badly adjusted and most probably unstable with real world tolerances.
